# using tastypie django-mptt's parent_id field becomes NULL during POST

Tags: tastypie, django-mptt

I would like to build the following tree:

top:

- son1
- son2

using mptt django tastypie (see bellow the following model and resource code).
instead of creating two children to the 'Top' record, it creates two trees (different tree_id) and the parent_id of son1 is Null.

```
head = {"content-type": "application/json"}

payload = { "user": {'id': 1}, 
            "parent": {'id': None}, 
            "name": 'Top' }

r = requests.post("{host}/api/v1/account/",
data=json.dumps(payload), headers=head)

# the id of the created record is e.g. 10

payload = { "user": {'id': 1}, 
            "parent": {'id': 10}, 
            "name": 'son1' }  

r = requests.post("{host}/api/v1/account/",
data=json.dumps(payload), headers=head) 

payload = { "user": {'id': 1}, 
            "parent": {'id': 10}, 
            "name": 'son2' }  

r = requests.post("{host}/api/v1/account/",
data=json.dumps(payload), headers=head)
```

NOTE:
if I'm using the full uri in the payload. e.g.

```
payload = { "user": '/api/v1/user/1/', 
            "parent": '/api/v1/account/10/', 
            "name": 'son1' }
```

then it works OK.

The model:

```
class Account(MPTTModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ' Account: %s' % self.name

class AccountResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    children = fields.ToManyField('self', 'children', null=True, full=True)
    parent = fields.ToOneField('self', 'parent', null=True)

    class Meta:
        serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        queryset = Account.objects.all().select_related('parent')
        include_resource_uri = False
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
                "id": ('exact'),
                "user": ('exact'),
                "name": ('exact'),
                "parent": ('exact'),
                "level": ('exact'),
                }
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        fields = []
        excludes = ['parent', 'rght', 'lft', 'level', 'tree_id']
```

what should I change in order to use the id only, without specifying the full uri and have this working correctly?

Updated: I realized that other weird stuff is happening when I use the above JSON code (and not the full uri), the password field in the user table becomes NULL. It looks like some sort of memory corruption.

Comment: Does changing the `id` key to `pk` work?

Comment: I just checked it again using pk instead of id. Still not working. This time it created a new record in the user table. with user id 2 and NULL password. (btw: what should it be id (as the field name) or pk?)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305169/django-tastypie-deletes-children-if-adding-other

Comment: Thanks a lot! OK, I'll stay with the full URI.