# Django TastyPie deletes children if adding other

Tags: django, post, foreign-keys, tastypie

I have one parent resource which can have more than one children of one attrbiute and one than more children of other attribute. They look like this:

```
class RouteResource(ModelResource):
    creator = fields.ForeignKey(UserProfileResource, 'creator', full=True)
    towns = fields.ToManyField(TownResource, 'towns', full=True, null=True)
```

model is:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    average_rate = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)

    creator = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    towns = models.ManyToManyField(Town)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

second resource is:

```
class MarkerResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    route = fields.ForeignKey(RouteResource, 'route')
    picture = fields.FileField(attribute="picture", null=True, blank=True)
```

and it's model is:

```
class Marker(models.Model):
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True, blank=True, max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    longitude = models.FloatField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()

    order = models.IntegerField()

    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
```

OK, now, I can successfuly add route with towns and my resource looks good:

```
{
. . .
. . .
"towns": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "my town",
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/town/1/"
    }
]
}
```

Now I would like to add one marker which has predefined route as foreign key by doing POST:

```
    {
        "description": "Center of earth",
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "order": 1,
        "picture": null,
      "route": {
        "id":59
      }
    }
```

after that my marker is successfully added to correct Route, but towns which I've added with route get removed so my route doesn't have any towns:

```
{
    "towns": []
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `id` with `pk`?

Comment: Then you have to provide the full resource uri instead of the dictionary. That's how tastypie hydrates the related resources.

Comment: Yeah, I wend with that solution in the end. Honestly I don't like that I have to put URL in one resource. That means one resource has to know URL of the other, but I believe ID would be enough

Comment: You have to create a custom field with overriden `build_related_resource` method, or a custom `hydrate_xxx` method in your resource (which would fetch the object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- provide full resource uri for the key's value, i.e: `route: "/api/v1/route/59/"`
- override the `hydrate_route` method of the `MarkerResource` to return an object given dictionary passed.
- create a custom field based off `fields.ForeignKey` that would implement custom `build_related_resource` behaviour.